# Why is the viewstate sent to the server on form POST different than the Viewstate in the form html?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web-scraping, headless-browser

I am attempting the scrape an ASP form. I was under the impression that, in order to get the form POST to be accepted, you had to send the fields of the form including viewstate, eventvalidation etc. When I do this, though, I go to an error page.

Looking into the values submitted by a browser, the viewstate sent to the server is different from the viewstate in the form's html. After searching everywhere I could think of, I still can't figure out why this is.

So, my question is: why is the viewstate sent to the server different, and how do I get the correct viewstate?

(This is more of a conceptual question which is why I haven't posted any code, but I'm working with phantomjs if that makes any difference)